# Shelve, Python, updating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

I am working with Shelve in Python and I am having an issue:

```
In [391]: x
Out[391]: {'broken': {'position': 25, 'page': 1, 'letter': 'a'}}

In [392]: x['broken'].update({'page':1,'position':25,'letter':'b'})

In [393]: x
Out[393]: {'broken': {'position': 25, 'page': 1, 'letter': 'a'}}
```

I don't understand why its not updating? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html). Basically, the keyword parameter `writeback` to `shelve.open` is responsible for this:

> If the optional `writeback` parameter is set to `True`, all entries
>   accessed are also cached in memory, and written back on `sync()` and
>   `close()`; this can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the
>   persistent dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can
>   consume vast amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the
>   close operation very slow since all accessed entries are written back
>   (there is no way to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor
>   which ones were actually mutated).

Example from the same page:

```
d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library
# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.
d.close()       # close it
```